# control autoresponder (out of office) via microsoft graph api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to control/activate/deactivate the out of office message for outlook365/exchange via the microsoft graph api?

In the Outlook ios app this feature is enabled, so I guess there must be a way. But I have no clue how to, because I can't find anything in the graph documentation

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, not currently. We're always adding to the API though, so stay tuned.